# rails g mongoid:config error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid4

I get this error when ever I run this command rails g mongoid:config. Does anybody have any idea

```
/home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug-3.5.1/lib/byebug/history.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug-3.5.1/lib/byebug/history.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug-3.5.1/lib/byebug/interface.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug-3.5.1/lib/byebug/interface.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug-3.5.1/lib/byebug/core.rb:5:in `require'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug-3.5.1/lib/byebug/core.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug-3.5.1/lib/byebug.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/byebug-3.5.1/lib/byebug.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /home/gardezi/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/gardezi/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

The commands that I ran are as followed below:

gem install mongoid

rails new blog

gedit /blog/Gemfile
    in which I wrote
    gem 'mongoid', '4.0.2'
    gem 'bson_ext'

and then I ran bundle

and then rails g mongoid:config

Thanks to Shweta the rails g command is not giving an error now but now I am encountering another problem and that is when ever I run this command it's running in infinite loop. It's been seven hours and still running so please tell me what should I do.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem. I just needed to stop the spring.

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps:

1] Skip active-record while creating new project

```
rails new blog -O
```

2] open Gemfile add gem 'mongoid'. No need to add gem 'bson_ext'

```
gem 'mongoid'
```

3] Install bundle

```
bundle install
```

4] Generate mongoid config file

```
rails g mongoid:config
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. this command started working but now this command is kind of running in  a infinite loop.

Comment: There's nothing in the log folder